# Create a csv file in adove xd plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins

I am writing a adove XD plugin. I am trying to save some data in a csv file and save it. But my code is not working.

```
const rows = [
  ["doc1", "layer1", "size1"],
  ["doc1", "layer2", "size2"]
];
const csvContent = `data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,${rows
  .map((e) => e.join(","))
  .join("n")}`;

const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "data.csv");
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click()
```

Comment: Yes I mean adove xd

Comment: Adove again ... [This](https://dribbble.com/tags/adove_xd)?

Comment: Yes this. I have mentioned Adove XD.